# Typescript edge cases mess up test coverage

Tags: typescript, ava, nyc

I have a project set up to use the AVA test runner and the NYC coverage tool. I am sure that I have 100% test coverage.

However, because I am using typescript, it seems that the typescript compiler added a bunch of polyfills with edge cases that aren‘t covered by my tests because there is simply no way to trigger them.

How do I get NYC to compute the correct coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It‘s me again! I figured it out!

It turns out I was correct in my assumption that edge cases in polyfills were the cause of the problem.

My solution was simple:

1. Install the `tslib` package
2. Set the compiler option `importHelpers` to `true`.

This way, nyc no longer recognizes the helpers as part of my code, and I get that sweet 100% coverage badge!